# Why does hyperlink style not cascade in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In the following HTML/CSS, why is the link color green and not blue, i.e. why does "p.description" override "#nav" but "p.description a" does not override "#nav a"?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #nav {
        color: black;   
    }
    #nav a {
        color: green;
    }
    p.description {
        color:red;
    }
    p.description a {
        color:blue;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav">
        <p class="description">This is a test and <a href="#">this is a link</a>.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809024/points-in-css-specificity

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because an id selector plus a type selector is more specific than two type selectors and a class selector. See [the specification on specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity).

So it does cascade, but the rules for the order in which the cascade happens are not what you thought they were.

Comment: Just to add value to the answer, he could be more specific by changing his selector to `#nav p.description a`

Answer (score -3):

Its green because the css rule #nav a {color: green;} stipulates it.

To make it blue do this #nav a {color: blue;}

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  He wants to know why it's behaving like this, and he only wants blue links within the description paragraph.