# When to use the !important property in CSS

Tags: html, css

Consider:

```
#div p {
    color: red !important;
}
...
#div p {
    color: blue;
}
```

I understand how `!important` works. In this case the div will render red because now it has priority (`!important`). But I can't still figure out an appropriate situation to use it in. Is there an example where `!important` saves the day?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules says that it's for overriding settings in user style sheets.

Comment: You need to use it a lot in some Wordpress themes because they use a lot of inline `style="{...}"` CSS and for that the only way to impose your own CSS is to alter PHP code or to use the `!important` property.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

### This is the real life scenario

Imagine this scenario

1. You have a global CSS file that sets visual aspects of your site globally.
2. You (or others) use inline styles on elements themselves which is <strike>usually</strike> very bad practice.

In this case you could set certain styles in your global CSS file as important, thus overriding inline styles set directly on elements.

### Actual real world example?

This kind of scenario usually happens when you don't have total control over your HTML. Think of solutions in [SharePoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharePoint) for instance. You'd like your part to be globally defined (styled), but some inline styles you can't control are present. `!important` makes such situations easier to deal with.

Other real life scenarios would also include some badly written **jQuery plugins** that also use inline styles...

**I suppose you got the idea by now** and can come up with some others as well.

### When do you decide to use `!important`?

I suggest you don't use `!important` unless you can't do it any other way. Whenever it's possible to avoid it, avoid it. Using lots of `!important` styles will make maintenance a bit harder, because you break the natural *cascading* in your stylesheets.

Comment: Real world example - site authors need to add a style, know how to do it, but don't know enough about specificity to force their style on the page. They can either go to the CSS developer to create a style for them, or if it's just a one-off situation, they can add an on-page `!important` declaration.

Comment: @Blowski: True, but that's a more complex example harder to explain to non CSS experts (not knowing what specificity means).

Comment: Another real world example: You are using a JavaScript Widget that is injecting some inline styles into a DOM element. Your only chance to overwrite an inline style is to use `!important`.

Comment: @acme: seems you've just been using such plugin and cursed heavens and earth because of it. :)

Comment: Unfortunately it's really happening quite often ;-)

Answer (score 20):

### Overwriting the Style Attribute

Say in the example that you are unable to change the HTML source code but only provide a stylesheet. Some thoughtless person has slapped on a style directly on the element (boo!)

```css
       div { background-color: green !important }
```

```html
    <div style="background-color:red">
    <p>Take that!</p>
    </div>
```

Here, !important can override inline CSS.

Answer (score 7):

This is a **real**, *real life* scenario, because it actually happened yesterday:

- *[Z-index in jQuery dialog. Autosuggest list not displayed properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693388/z-index-in-jquery-dialog-autosuggest-list-not-displayed-properly#5693787)*

Alternatives to not using `!important` in my answer included:

- Hunting down in JavaScript/CSS where a certain elusive property was being applied.
- Adding the property with JavaScript, which is little better than using `!important`.

So, a benefit of `!important` is that it sometimes saves time. If you use it very sparingly like this, it can be a useful tool.

If you're using it just because you don't understand how [**specificity works**](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), you're doing it wrong.

---

Another use for `!important` is when you're writing some kind of external widget type thing, and you want to be sure that your styles will be the ones applied, see:

- *[Appended control's CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845494/appended-controls-css-problem)*

Comment: I guess you're aware that squashing a bug by dropping an Acme anvil on it isn't always the right choice? Some benevolent and friendly creatures might perish, too. Please learn how to use your favorite browser's debugging tools. Chrome's developer tools have an option to place a breakpoint on attribute change (including *inline* style change) on an element. If in the end you discover you have no control over the JavaScript that is makeing the change, you can always decide to drop the anvil anyway...

Answer (score 4):

You generally use !important when you've run out of other ways to increase the specificity of a CSS selector.

So once another CSS rule has already dabbled with Ids, inheritance paths and class names, when  you need to override that rule then you need to use 'important'.

Answer (score 3):

`!important` is somewhat like `eval`. It isn't a good solution to any problem, and there are very few problems that can't be solved without it.

Answer (score 3):

I have to use `!important` when I need to overwrite the style of an HTML generated by some JavaScript "plugin" (like advertising, banners, and stuff) that uses the "style" attribute.

So I guess that you can use it when you don't control the CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking you shouldn't need to use !important if you've structured your CSS well and don't have too many degrees of specificity.

The most appropriate time to use !important is when you have one exceptional style that you want to style outside of your site's normal cascade.

Answer (score 2):

Using `!important` is generally not a good idea in the code itself, but it can be useful in various overrides.

I use Firefox and a dotjs plugin which essentially can run your own custom JS or CSS code on specified websites automatically.

Here's the code for it I use on Twitter that makes the tweet input field always stay on my screen no matter how far I scroll, and for the hyperlinks to always remain the same color.

```
a, a * {
  color: rgb(34, 136, 85) !important;  
}

.count-inner {
 color: white !important;   
}

.timeline-tweet-box {
 z-index: 99 !important;
position: fixed !important;
left: 5% !important;   
}
```

Since, thankfully, Twitter developers don't use `!important` properties much, I can use it to guarantee that the specified styles will be definitely overridden, because without `!important` they were not overridden sometimes. It really came in handy for me there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a real-world example.

While working with GWT-Bootstrap V2, it will inject some CSS file, which will override my CSS styles. In order to make my properties to be not overridden, I used `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `!important` is very import in email creation when inline `CSS` is the correct answer. It is used in conjunction with `@media` to change the layout when viewing on different platforms. For instance the way the page looks on desktop as compare to smart phones (ie. change the link placement and size. have the whole page fit within a `480px` width as apposed to `640px` width.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `!important` to change the style of an element on a SharePoint web part. The JavaScript code that builds the elements on the web part is buried many levels deep in the SharePoint inner-workings.

Attempting to find where the style is applied, and then attempting to modify it seems like a lot of wasted effort to me. Using the `!important` tag in a custom CSS file is much, much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I am planning to use `!important` for a third-party widget meant to be embedded in a large number of websites out of my control.

I reached the conclusion `!important` is the only solution to protect the widget's stylesheet from the host stylesheet (apart from iframe and inline styles, which are equally bad). For instance, WordPress uses:

```
#left-area ul {
    list-style-type: disc;
    padding: 0 0 23px 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
}
```

This rule threathens to override any UL in my widget because id's have strong specificity. In that case, systematic use of `!important` seems to be one of the few solutions.

Answer (score -2):

You use `!important` to override a `css` property.

For example, you have a control in ASP.NET and it renders a control with a background blue (in the HTML). You want to change it, and you don't have the source control so you attach a new CSS file and write the same selector and change the color and after it add `!important`.

Best practices is when you are branding / redesigning SharePoint sites, you use it a lot to override the default styles.

Comment: This answer seems unnecessarily specific.