# jQuery if myDiv is:visible, addclass to another element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been getting into jQuery again and obviously I'm missing something.

I want to add a class to an element depending on if another one is visible.

It's hidden with `display: none;` and activated with `slideToggle`

I have this:

```
if ($("#about_me").is(':visible')){
        $("#about_me_clicker").addClass(".about_highlight"); 
    } else {
}
```

Now I'm assuming I've gotten it totally wrong, so [here's a fiddle for you to see](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/YVqJ7/).

How can I add this class to the certain div, if the other one is :visible?

Thanks.

### Edit:

To make things clear, I will be only applying the class to the one element.

Comment: Write this line $("#about_me_clicker").addClass("about_highlight"); instead of $("#about_me_clicker").addClass(".about_highlight");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
$("#about_me_clicker").addClass(".about_highlight");
```

To:

```
$("#about_me_clicker").addClass("about_highlight");
```

You don't need to include the `.` in the class names for `addClass`.

Also, in your fiddle's CSS:

```
.about_highlight
{
    color; #f00;
}
```

Should be:

```
.about_highlight
{
    color: #f00;
}
```

Another note, in CSS, ids take precedence over classes.  So even though the div has class `about_highlight`, the color declared in `#about_me_clicker` will be active.

<strike>To fix this you can use `!important`.</strike>

```
.about_highlight
{
    color: #f00 !important;
}
```

To fix this, just make a more specific CSS rule.

```
#about_me_clicker.about_highlight
{
    color: #f00;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YVqJ7/20/

Comment: Damn typos! And really i should have seen the precedence override... I think it's time for a break.. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem.  Oh, you also missed a `{` at the end of your CSS  :-P

Comment: @BNL: I'm aware `!important` is bad, but how else can you make the color precedence work, and still be able to use the class on other elements?

Comment: That wasn't part of the question. :) Removed the -1 anyway.

Comment: Maybe I should have made it clear that the class would only be applied to this element.

Comment: Thanks Rocket.. Now I've hit another wall.. http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/YVqJ7/22/

Comment: @Kyle: What's the problem?  When the page loads `#about_me` is hidden.  If you want the color to change, put the code inside the click handler.

Comment: Omg of course.. I am so not awake. I'm going for coffee. Thanks very mcuh :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of errors in that fiddle:

```
color; #f00;
```

Should be a colon not a semi-colon.

```
$("#about_me_clicker").addClass(".about_highlight");
```

Remove the `.` should just be the name of the class.

You are missing a `}` at the end of your CSS.

And finally, your `#about_me_clicker` css takes precedence over the `.about_highlight` one.

Comment: #about_me_clicker.about_highlight { color: #f00; } /* fixed style */

Comment: @BNL: That's assuming he only has one element that can have the class `about_highlight`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

http://jsfiddle.net/genesis/YVqJ7/8/

added `!important` into color and also remove dot in `addClass(".about_highlight")` (so it's `addClass("about_highlight")`)

Comment: just a note but `!important` is such bad practice in such simple css.

Comment: @f0x: this one was important. Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/genesis/YVqJ7/14/) I have just deleted that !important and it's not working anymore

Comment: indeed, but there are much more elegant ways to fix it. it's a colour damnit ;) see @kingjiv's answer to see the reason behind it. Rather suggest a css refactor.

Comment: @f0x: no, my one has it all corrected, but withhout !important it just doesn't work.

Comment: I used to use !important too, then I learned about css specificity.

Comment: #about_me_clicker.about_highlight { color: #f00; } /* no !important */

Comment: @gen, the css part of his answer >_>

Comment: @f0x: `color; #f00;` ? I have fixed it already! and that bracket added, too. Take a look into @Rocket fiddle

Comment: I changed the selector to be more specific. http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/YVqJ7/19/

Comment: @gen , css precedence - ie. it will choose an ID CSS Rule before a Class Rule. Hence the need for `!important` a simple css refactor or selector refinement would be much better. Valid(ish) times to use `!important` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701149/when-to-use-important-property-in-css not for simple things ... like colour in css you control.

Answer (score -1):

just without dot

```
if ($("#about_me").is(':visible')){
  $("#about_me_clicker").addClass("about_highlight");
} else {}
```