# How to change category div color

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

Okay so I have my categories wrapped in a div

```
<div id="categoryf">
  <?php $category = get_the_category();  echo $category[0]->cat_name;?>
</div>
```

and it shows only first category,the way I want it, but my requirement is to get the  certain categories into different div so that I can assign different background color.

How would I achive this.

edit here is my css

```
#categoryf{ 
  position:absolute;
  padding:4px;
  width:auto;
  height:13px;
  margin-top:-86px;
  font-family:abeatbykairegular;
  font-weight:200;
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight:bold;
  letter-spacing:6px;
  color:#fff;
  background:#2d0748;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:2;
}

#categoryf a:link,
#categoryf a:visited{ 
color:#fff;
}
#categoryf a:hover{ 
color:#af77c0;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: how is `$category[0]->cat_name` rendered?

Comment: I think that only shows the first category, if there is more than one category to the post it only shows the first category

Comment: Why don't you use CSS to define the colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the category slug, and then create CSS classes for those.

```
<?php $category = get_the_category(); ?>
<div id="categoryf" class="category-<?php echo $category[0]->slug ?>">
    <?php echo $category[0]->cat_name;?>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

To have some categories a different color and others the same color. Just define a `category-common` class and include that.

```
<?php $category = get_the_category(); ?>
<div id="categoryf" class="category-common category-<?php echo $category[0]->slug ?>">
    <?php echo $category[0]->cat_name;?>
</div>
```

Then in the CSS you can apply styles like this.

```
.category-common {
      background-color: blue;
}

.category-business {
      background-color: green;
}
```

Make sure to define the `category-common` first in the CSS, and then for any category you want a different color for just declare the class for based upon the slug.

Comment: Nothing happened the background color didn't change I updated and added my css @Mathew Foscarini

Comment: If the CSS class is set correctly, but it does not change the background. Try using `!important` to force that style.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701149/when-to-use-important-property-in-css

Comment: I got it to work, but what about all the other categories that i want to remain one color, would I have to make a different class for them all @Mathew Foscarini