# radio button looks like checkbox in IE (and some FF)

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have created website where I have radio buttons.

When I look them in Chrome, they looks fine.

But when I open them in IE, they looks like checkbox. They have square radio.

I tried with below CSS,

```
.radio, input[type=radio] {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

but still the square part is there. I don't know whether its shadow or something else.

You can check that at

http://www.smartprojects-kw.com/faces/survey.xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On inspecting your code, it seems the problem is because of **`background`** attribute not **`box-shadow/border`**.

```
input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
background: #999;  //------ Reason for problem
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

Remove the **`background`** attribute, it will be not shown.

Comment: @FahimParkar Oh you got it. I thought of adding a screenshot.  Anyway glad to help you :)

Comment: I had that in my survey.xhtml file. I was looking in my CSS file ;) sometimes eyes don't catch everything... :D :P

Comment: @FahimParkar Yup, usually happens.  This is where the **developer tools** of browsers gives the **rescue hand** ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just insert these piece  in your Code

```
input[type="radio"] {                        
    border: 0px ;
}
```

Or Do this

you have to add a CSS class "check" ..

`<input class="check" type ....`

and in the styles.css ...

```
input.check {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Hope this will help you out..

Comment: `!important` isn't a good solution, it may break other other styles.  If you get some time, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/5701193/1671639

Comment: Oh k k fine i just inserted the solution for the question.. anyway thanks for correcting it @user1671639