# Bootstrap Button Outline Still Working Only On click

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/vuPeN/1/) I tried to remove Buttons Blue Highlight/ Glow on click by using the following CSS roles:

```
.btn:focus { outline: none;}
.btn:hover { outline: none;}
.btn.active{ outline: none;}
.btn{outline: none;}
```

But I am still getting a very fast Highlight ONLY at Click time on the button and it disappears very fast after the class is active or have focus. Can you please let me know which portion of CSS is doing this and how I can stop it? Thanks

Comment: are u using Google Chrome? i think its the chrome's behavior to highlight focused elements. its different in other browsers.

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 4):

Use `!important` flag because the `outline` property is changed by other CSS styles probably:

You only need:

```
.btn {   
    outline: none !important;
}
```

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5701149/1420197) about `!important` flag.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vuPeN/3/)