# Change all text colors on a website

Tags: html, css

I am currently using Asp.Net MVC 5, how do I change the font color on every page to a specific color?

I am currently using the bootstrap style sheets and am trying to style the site.

Is there a over-arching css class which will change all of the font color's to a specific color?

Comment: You want the default color or literally every color ever used anywhere a single color?

Comment: `*{color:#ff0000 !important;}` ?

Comment: [Eric Lippert's Purple Crayon](http://blog.codinghorror.com/eric-lipperts-purple-crayon/).

Comment: Try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701149/when-to-use-important-property-in-css. Also remember that the last css "sheet" is the over-rider before <style> and inline.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I would like to change the default text color to orange (#FF6600)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MVC you'd have a global css file included on every page.  Then to set the default color you could use:

```
html, body{
  color: #ff6600;
}
```

If you wanted an high viable override of other styles (not recommended) then:

```
html *, body *{
  color: #ff6600 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very simple question. All you need to use would be `body *` or `*` as a CSS selector in a CSS file. It will select *all* of the elements--be it `<div>` or `<p>`, `<img>` or `<q>`, it'll get them. Example of use:

```
* {
  color: #333333;     
}
```