# Wordpress Child Them CSS Rule display:none gets overriden

Tags: css, wordpress, html-lists

I have this DOM Tree:

```
<ul id="menu-horizontalnav" class="menu">

    <li id="menu-item-19">

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-99" ></li>

        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Now I want that  the `<ul class="sub-menu">` and his child content is hidden.
I added a new .css rule to my style.css file:

[image]

But as you can see it gets overriden by this rule:

[image]

If I deactivate `display: block;` everything works.

My Quesiton is how can I add a .css rule which is only valid for the `class="sub-menu"`
without getting this rule overriden by the rule `.menu ul`

In my Understanding from the .css rules the `display: none;` rule should override the
`display: block;` rule, because it is deeper in the hiracy

I added my code in the style.css file in my child theme

Comment: Add !important to your display: none

Comment: It gets overridden because the `display:block;` declared latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trivial way would be to overwrite the CSS rule by marking it as important:

```
.sub-menu {
    display: none !important;
}
```

But this technique should be avoided if at all possible for [various reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701149/when-to-use-important-property-in-css).

The better way would be to explicitely address the place the `sub-menu` class takes in the DOM hierarchy in your css:

```
.menu ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

This instruction is more specific than just using `.menu ul` and will thus be preferred by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
  hideMenu
  {   
    display:none !important;
  }
```

Whenever you want to hide , add this class using `addClass` or just add the property alone.

Whenever you want to remove this, `removeClass` or remove the property.

Comment: I just impressed for your 246K. U edited my answer. Glad for that

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following css:

```
ul .submenu {display:none !important;}
```

It should solve your problem and override the ul.menu class