# Override css rules

Tags: html, css

html file

```
 <ul id="navbar">
            <li class="selected">
                <a href="#"> HOME</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"> ABOUT US</a>
            </li>
  </ul>
```

css file

```
  ul#navbar li {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  }
```

and now I want to add bottom border to green color only on active list item.

```
 .selected {
 border-bottom: 5px solid #37F053;  
 }
```

but this does not work well. it still has the #aaa bottom border color

Comment: You can add `!imporant` to any rule to override other rules already set. http://jsfiddle.net/60k6mtve/ ... Or you can change your CSS specificity level.

Comment: In term of [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) `ul#navbar li` has a higher value than `.selected` class selector. Instead, use: `ul#navbar li.selected`

Comment: thanks,works now @HashemQolami

Comment: @CMadi `!important` [should](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701149/when-to-use-important-property-in-css) [be](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css) [the last](http://james.padolsey.com/css/dont-use-important/) option to choose.

Answer (score 1):

Using !important everywhere is bad practice. It means you don't have control on your style-sheet. Correct rule will be:

```
ul#navbar li.selected {
   border-bottom: 5px solid #37F053;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `.selected` to `ul#navbar li.selected`