# Border not working as expected for thead tr

Tags: html, css

I want the whole of a row in the thead to have a specified border but it is not working as expected when I am using border styling attribute. But it is working using outline attribute. Here is a code snippet:

```css
table.table, table.table * {
   border: none !important;
  }

table.price-table thead tr {
   border: 10px solid blue;
   outline: thin solid red;

  
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table price-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Ticket Type</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr data-ticket-id=1>
      <td class="category-ticket">Adult</td>
      <td class="price-ticket">RM 20</td>
    </tr>



    <tr data-ticket-id=3>
      <td class="category-ticket">Child</td>
      <td class="price-ticket">RM 15</td>

    </tr> 



  </tr>                
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `border: none !important;` overrides your second `border` declaration. The use of `!important` is not recommended unless it is strictly necessary. It makes maintainability a lot harder. For more information [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701149/when-to-use-important-property-in-css).

Comment: I don't need it either. I was doing it for testing. Thanks for the catch. Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Remove following css:

```
table.table, table.table * {
            border: none !important;
        }
```

The above css will effect to not display border. Because you have given `table.table *`  So, it will target all the elements of the table. and you have given `!important` so, no other css will override the `none` css.

```css
table.price-table thead tr {
   border: 10px solid blue;
   outline: thin solid red;

  
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table price-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Ticket Type</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr data-ticket-id=1>
      <td class="category-ticket">Adult</td>
      <td class="price-ticket">RM 20</td>
    </tr>



    <tr data-ticket-id=3>
      <td class="category-ticket">Child</td>
      <td class="price-ticket">RM 15</td>

    </tr> 



  </tr>                
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your this styling

```
table.table, table.table * {
            border: none !important;
        }
```

is over-riding all elements `border` styling to `none` beacuse of `*` you used. So if you want to apply please change this property to something you want. 
And please avoid using `!important` unless it is too important and you want to over-write some library or framework default styling.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your css:

```
table.table, table.table * {
    }

table.price-table thead tr {
    border: 1px solid red;
    outline: thin solid red;
}
```

check it working: https://jsfiddle.net/Aschab/6p6kht43/

As an advice, if you need !important for your css to work, you're doing it wrong. Think outside the box