# Specificity issues with bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why do I need `!important` for the margin:0 to show?

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

.alert {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

and

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

Comment: answer is already explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701149/when-to-use-important-property-in-css

Comment: where? I know what `!important` does I don't know why I need it to override bootstrap.css when bootstrap.css is imported before my own css.