# `font` by itself seems to make `font-style` unchangeable

Tags: javascript, css

In the following, when I combine `font-size` and `font-family` into `font`, and then use JS to change the `new-style` class, the line `font-style: italic;` line is ignored:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <title>Chapter 9, Example 5</title>
  <style>
    #divAdvert {
      font: 12pt Arial;
    }
    .new-style {
      text-decoration: underline;
      font-style: italic;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="divAdvert">
    Here is an advertisement. Why doesn't this italicize?
  </div>
  <br><button onclick="clickMeh();">Click Meh</button>

  <script>
    function clickMeh() {
      var divAdvert = document.getElementById("divAdvert");
      divAdvert.className = "new-style";
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/globewalldesk/pen/LLOJqR).

But when I separate them, the line is italicized as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <title>Chapter 9, Example 5</title>
  <style>
    #divAdvert {
      font-size: 12pt;
      font-family: Arial;
    }
    .new-style {
      text-decoration: underline;
      font-style: italic;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="divAdvert">
    Here is an advertisement.
  </div>
  <br><button onclick="clickMeh();">Click Meh</button>

  <script>
    function clickMeh() {
      var divAdvert = document.getElementById("divAdvert");
      divAdvert.className = "new-style";
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/globewalldesk/pen/rwYror).

Why???????

UPDATE: Thanks to input from Evgeny and Michael, I managed to get it working simply by adding `#divAdvert` in front of `.new-style` (in the CSS) and I think that's the most correct answer. This preserves the ID and recognizes the fact that the `new-style` class is entirely dependent on the ID. [Codepen here](https://codepen.io/globewalldesk/pen/VWrEqd).

Answer (score 3):

It's a [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue. `font` on `#divAdvert` will overwrite all font properties defined by a rule with lower specificity, and a class has lower specificity than an id. You just need to match or use higher specificity for the change.

I would either style `#divAdvert` with a class as the selector (what I did below) and append the new class instead of overwriting it, or you can use `#divAdvert.new-style` instead of `.new-style` in your selector. In general, I try to avoid using ID's to style things though because you run into issues like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <title>Chapter 9, Example 5</title>
  <style>
    .divAdvert {
      font: 12pt Arial;
    }
    .new-style {
      text-decoration: underline;
      font-style: italic;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="divAdvert" class="divAdvert">
    Here is an advertisement. Why doesn't this italicize?
  </div>
  <br><button onclick="clickMeh();">Click Meh</button>

  <script>
    function clickMeh() {
      var divAdvert = document.getElementById("divAdvert");
      divAdvert.classList.add('new-style');
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The italicized font is not Arial, I think you want to add new-style to the class list rather than overwrite it?

Answer (score 1):

Because the `#ID` is higher in the hierarchy than a `.class` and `font` by itself contains all its sub properties, so even if you don't write them then they are just taken as defaults.

You can also use `font-style: italic !important;` in the `.class`

Comment: No, don't use `!important`, especially here where it is completely unnecessary. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5701149/215552.

Comment: I'm speaking in general... lol... but yes, try to avoid `!important`.

Comment: I get that it's important to avoid `!important` in order to keep the code maintainable, but I do love how this neatly solves the problem while illustrating what the original problem was.

Comment: Maybe just use:

`#divAdvert {
      font: 12pt Arial;
    }
    #divAdvert.new-style {
      text-decoration: underline;
      font-style: italic;
    }`

Comment: Maybe the _real_ moral of the story is to avoid `font` by itself.

Comment: Exactly, and then you don't need !important :)