# Increase height of jumbotron

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to increase height of my jumbotron without giving it in class because then it will be no more responsive.
I wanna make [this](https://www.screencast.com/t/SzEPL5mDnVo0). But mine look like [this](https://www.screencast.com/t/USGYgyq55e)

Here is my code
Html:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <h2 class="meeting_heading">MeetingResult is dedicated to ridding the world of ineffective, under-performing and outright wasteful business meetings.</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-ms-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-custom">Learn More</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container 
{
    width:87%;
}
.jumbotron
{
    box-shadow: inset 0px -8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 13px;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    min-height:300px;
}
.btn-custom
{
    width: 152px;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    border: none;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size: 21.994px;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding: 15px 20px 16px;
    position: relative;
    top: 13px;
    right: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use padding?

Comment: it seems like working fine [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z7Lr0133/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's working fine..

But there should be another situation in your side, that your `jumbotron` may be inherited from it's parent so you need to use `padding` there and make that rule important like this..

```
    .jumbotron {
        padding: 48px 60px !important;
    }
```

Or you can use `min-height` as you are using already like:

```
    .jumbotron {
        min-height: 300px !important;
    }
```

It may solve your problem...!

Comment: What's the use of !important?

Comment: [use of !important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701149/when-to-use-important-property-in-css)