# How can I delete the highlight color for nodes

Tags: css, primeng

I have an PrimeNg Tree (Angular 2) and I want to delete the selected nodes highlight color.

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEgcH.jpg)

Based on the image I want to delete the blue highlight color.

Instead I want to get this style: [Style I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKinH.jpg)

Here are my styles:

```
.ui-tree {
  width: 100%;
}

body .ui-widget-content {
  border: none !important;
}

span.ui-treenode-label {
  font-family: Poppins !important;
  line-height: 24px !important;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  padding-left: 5px !important;
  padding-right: 5px !important;
}

span.ui-treenode-icon {
  line-height: 24px !important;
  font-size: 1.2rem !important;
}

.ui-tree .ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-icon {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.ui-tree .ui-treenode-children {
  padding-left: 20px !important;
}

.hidden-tree-node {
  display: none;
}

.ui-state-highlight .ui-widget-content {
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the original style by setting:

```
span.ui-state-highlight {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: I would not say never... It's not always bad to use !important. But you must know where to use it. And in most cases it's better to avoid it with some well planned CSS. But as he is overriding an existing CSS with a deep selector, I can't see a bad practice to use it in this case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701149/when-to-use-the-important-property-in-css

Comment: That's worked for me!, thanks!

Do you know how Can I change the folder color?

Answer (score 1):

A few solutions:

1) Use ng-deep

```
::ng-deep {
  span.ui-state-highlight {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: inherit;
  }
}
```

2)Target the element in a more specific way

```
span.ui-treenode-label.ui-corner-all.ui-state-highlight {
   background-color: transparent;
   color: inherit;
}
```

Also, try to use SASS. It will make your CSS more readable and smarter. You will love it. By the way you should remove the importance from your code. using importants is not good practice.

Comment: +1 - this solution allows the user to avoid using the CSS important rule. This is rarely a good idea. See: https://uxengineer.com/css-specificity-avoid-important-css/