# CSS Why is this tablecell not left aligned?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm attempting to create a table with the first cell left justified, and all the other cells centered.

I am able to do this, but thought I'd use a different CSS technique, and it's got me stumped.

In the example below, i would think the table cell with class="left" would take precedence over the table level center alignment, but this does not seem to be the case.  All cells are centered.

All inputs appreciated!

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        td {border:solid 1px black;}

        table.SomeTable td {text-align:center;}

        td.Left {text-align:Left;}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="SomeTable" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:100px;" class="Left">Why not left justified?</td>
            <td style="width:100px;">aaa</td>
            <td style="width:100px;">aaa</td>
            <td style="width:100px;">aaa</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `table.SomeTable td` rule is indeed more specific than `td.Left`.

You can fix it by adding the table class:

```
table.SomeTable td.Left {text-align:Left;}
```

here's some background on how CSS specificity works:  [Points in CSS specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809024/points-in-css-specificity)