# Override property value when additional class is added to an element

Tags: css

I have always thought that if a property was defined after the previous property like I have as follows, that it would overwrite the previous value. But for some reason when using `input[type=button]` this isn't the case.

However, when changing `input[type=button]` to a class such as `.btn` the value overrides the previous, why is this? Is there a way around this without using `!important`?

```css
input[type=button] {
  color: red;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.accent {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Hello" class="accent">
```

Comment: see my update on how to calculate exactly the specificity...

Comment: did another update to tell you the exact specificity input[type=button] vs. .accent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the specificity of the attribute selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406953/what-is-the-specificity-of-the-attribute-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have always thought that if a property was defined after the previous property [...] that it would overwrite the previous value.

This is only true if these selectors have the same specificity.

## Actual Specificity

```
input[type=button] /* specificity = 11 */
.accent /* specificity = 10 */
```

Imagine

```
<input type="button" id="id" class="class">

#id {}
.class {} /* will of course never ever override #id */
#id.class {} /* will override as well */
```

Each selector has his points that get summed up when combined.

**There is also a nice "hack" if you must increase your selectors specificity:**

```
.class {} will be overridden by .class.class {}
```

```css
input[type=button] {
  color: red;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.accent.accent {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Hello" class="accent">
```

*Nice read anyway*: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

**BTW** I remember there is a very good website where you can read exactly how many points each selector has (id is strongest) but I can't find the resource anymore...

**EDIT**

## Calculating Specificity

```
*               /* a=0 b=0 c=0 -> specificity =   0 */
LI              /* a=0 b=0 c=1 -> specificity =   1 */
UL LI           /* a=0 b=0 c=2 -> specificity =   2 */
UL OL+LI        /* a=0 b=0 c=3 -> specificity =   3 */
H1 + *[REL=up]  /* a=0 b=1 c=1 -> specificity =  11 */
UL OL LI.red    /* a=0 b=1 c=3 -> specificity =  13 */
LI.red.level    /* a=0 b=2 c=1 -> specificity =  21 */
#x34y           /* a=1 b=0 c=0 -> specificity = 100 */
#s12:not(FOO)   /* a=1 b=0 c=1 -> specificity = 101 */
```

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity

Comment: `.accent.accent`, that seems like a cool little trick. Is that bad practice though?

Comment: So in the end, all I had to do was take `input[type=button]` and change it to `[type=button]`

Answer (score 2):

This is because `input[type=button]` is more specific then the class. You can fix this by adding the class to `input`.

```css
input[type=button] {
  color: red;
  background-color: transparent;
}

input.accent {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Hello" class="accent">
```

Answer (score 1):

Involving html attributes on top of html tag is a more refined selector than a class that is why it gets the priority in css.
 so you can refine the selector using `input.accent` and it will override.

You can have a look at this article which talk about css internal priorities: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Instead of using non-standard and potentially confusing terms like "refined" and "priorities", why not just consistently use the correct term, which is "specificity"?