# What is the rule behind "CSS 256 Classes Override One ID"?

Tags: css

I have came through this situation recently but unable to find 'Why'?
Can anyone explain?

See the example below at: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lzjqh

Comment: If you can find the link, surely you can find the explanation... it's literally plastered all over the Web right now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Points in CSS specificity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809024/points-in-css-specificity)

Comment: @My Head Hurts: Not really... that explains why the points explanation is flawed but it doesn't address the bug being demonstrated here.

Comment: @My Head Hurts: It looks to me that the accepted answer would answer this question too. That said it still doesn't make this question any more of a duplicate *or* that answer any less misdirected...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens due to a browser limitation, and not a mistake in the spec or how browsers implement it.

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) says:

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> - count the number of ID selectors in the selector (= a)
> - count the number of class selectors, attributes selectors, and pseudo-classes in the selector (= b)
> - count the number of type selectors and pseudo-elements in the selector (= c)
> - ignore the universal selector
>
> Selectors inside the negation pseudo-class are counted like any other, but the negation itself does not count as a pseudo-class.
>
> Concatenating the three numbers a-b-c (in a number system with a large base) gives the specificity.

Browsers have to store specificity values as integers for the purposes of calculation, and somehow a value of 256 causes an overflow depending on the browser. This usually happens with an 8-bit unsigned integer, whose max value is 255; adding one more causes the class-level specificity to somehow be "upgraded" into an ID-level value, making it equal to the ID in the cascade and thereby overriding it.

Comment: I think this answer sums it up nicely enough. I was going to expand it, but see the question linked in the comments. I may move my answer over if there's a need to explain the disparity between the spec, and implementation details in browsers.

Comment: Begs the question of why specificity isn't capped at 9n. Is anyone really going to ever have more than 9 class, attribute or pseudo-classes featured in one selector? Being capped at 9, specificty score would only ever have to be stored in decimal and an infinite number of classes could never out-score a single ID, as `90` < `100`.

Comment: @James Donnelly: As a matter of fact, Selectors 4 does state that implementations should cap specificity values and not allow them to overflow.

Comment: That's very interesting to know, I hadn't considered looking there as I'd assumed it would remain the same. Neat!

Comment: @James Donnelly: Yeah, in fact, it was added in direct response to the specificity hack that you see here. The last thing we need is authors hacking in 256 selectors for the sake of specificity workarounds.

Answer (score 5):

This is all explained in a article:

[extreme-specificity](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/extreme-specificity)