# Have two elements appear when their container is hovered, and then have one disappear when the other is hovered specifically?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have two navigational elements that are set up as columns on either side of an image.  You can see them in place at [my website, here](http://www.element17.com/).  Click on any image and after it loads, hover over it.

What I'm trying to accomplish is as follows:

1. When the cursor is outside of the image, both nav buttons are set at 0% opacity.
2. When the image is hovered in the center (not over either of the two nav buttons), both nav buttons are set at 50% opacity.
3. When either nav button is hovered directly, it is set at 100% opacity and the other nav button is set at 0% opacity.

This isn't working at the moment.  HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="sb-body">
    <a id="sb-nav-previous" class="sb-bignav" title="Previous" onclick="Shadowbox.previous()"></a>
    <a id="sb-nav-next" class="sb-bignav" title="Next" onclick="Shadowbox.next()"></a>
    <div id="sb-body-inner">
        <img style="position: absolute;" src="Corrosion.jpg" id="sb-player" height="405" width="609">
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS is as follows:

```
    #sb-nav-next {
    right:0;
    background:url('../images/nav-right.png') center center no-repeat;
}

#sb-nav-previous {
    left:0;
    background:url('../images/nav-left.png') center center no-repeat;
}

#sb-body:hover .sb-bignav {
    opacity:0.5;
    -webkit-opacity:0.5;
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
}

#sb-nav-next:hover #sb-nav-previous, 
#sb-nav-previous:hover #sb-nav-next {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-opacity:0;
    -moz-opacity:0;
}

.sb-bignav {
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    z-index:400;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-opacity:0;
    -moz-opacity:0;
    transition: opacity .125s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .125s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity .125s ease-in;
}

.sb-bignav:hover {
    opacity:1.0;
    -webkit-opacity:1.0;
    -moz-opacity:1.0;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zNkcQ/

Comment: Check out [this site](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) for sibling selectors.

Comment: Unfortunately, these selectors only work for _succeeding_ siblings, not preceding ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *can* be done using pure CSS, but, you need to move the previous and next elements past the inner body element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/c5Xn3/

CSS:

```
#sb-body-inner { 
    height: 405px; 
} 
/* This is the height of the image inside the slider.
If you do not change this line than #sb-body-inner will be about 20px tall and 
will not trigger the hover event */

#sb-body-inner:hover ~ #sb-nav-previous.sb-bignav,
#sb-body-inner:hover ~ #sb-nav-next.sb-bignav { 
    opacity: 0.5; 
}

#sb-nav-previous.sb-bignav:hover,
#sb-nav-next.sb-bignav:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    -webkit-opacity: 1.0;
    -moz-opacity: 1.0;
}

.sb-bignav {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 400;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .125s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .125s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity .125s ease-in;
}

#sb-nav-next {
    right: 0;
    background: url('http://www.element17.com/images/nav-right.png') center center no-repeat;
}

#sb-nav-previous {
    left: 0;
    background: url('http://www.element17.com/images/nav-left.png') center center no-repeat;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sb-body">
    <div id="sb-body-inner">
        <img style="position: absolute;" src="http://www.element17.com/gallery/01_CONSTRUCTS/Shear.jpg" id="sb-player" height="405" width="609">
    </div>
    <a id="sb-nav-previous" class="sb-bignav" title="Previous" onclick="Shadowbox.previous()"></a>
    <a id="sb-nav-next" class="sb-bignav" title="Next" onclick="Shadowbox.next()"></a>
</div>
```

​

Comment: Your welcome, the only catch is that #sb-body-inner has to be the exact same height as the navigation arrows. Otherwise, you'll have spots that don't trigger the hover.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've exhausted all of my references for a css solution to this problem.  The issue is that you'll never get the left nav overlay to become transparent because there is no way to select an element's preceding sibling.  I used
`#sb-body .sb-bignav:hover ~ .sb-bignav {
    opacity: 0;
}` 
with success on getting the right nav overlay to become transparent, but that's it.

I suggest using jQuery to do this:

**OLD**

```
$('.sb-bignav:hover').siblings().css('opacity', 0);
```

**NEW**

```
$('.sb-bignav').hover( function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.css('opacity', 1);
    self.siblings('.sb-bignav').css('opacity', 0);
}, function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.css('opacity', .5);
    self.siblings('.sb-bignav').css('opacity', .5);
});
```

Comment: Nick, can you elaborate on how to implement this jQuery?  I've got (in a <script> element):
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.sb-bignav:hover').siblings().css({
            'opacity': 0,
            '-webkit-opacity': 0,
            '-moz-opacity': 0
        });
    });

But this is not working...

Comment: @NaOH, I've never used the JSON input style for .css(), but a quick look at the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/css/) shows that what you have should work.  Try wrapping the numerical inputs in quotes, though.  It shouldn't make a difference, but it wouldn't hurt to try.

Comment: @NaOH, my original code would never work because there were no 'hovered' elements when the DOM loaded.  Instead, I've added a hover event binder to the elements in question and modified their and their sibling's behavior in the handler functions.  I've run this on your website with success.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is the specificity of each selector. The more specific (more points) overrides the less specific (fewer points).

ID: 100 points

Class: 10 points

Element: 1 point

Then, this rule has 110 points:

```
#sb-body:hover .sb-bignav {
    opacity:0.5;
    -webkit-opacity:0.5;
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
}
```

Below, the rule has 10 points and is being overwritten by the previous rule with 110:

```
.sb-bignav:hover {
    opacity:1.0;
    -webkit-opacity:1.0;
    -moz-opacity:1.0;
}​
```

Try this CSS:

```
#sb-nav-next {
    right:0;
    background:url('http://www.element17.com/images/nav-right.png') center center no-repeat;
}

#sb-nav-previous {
    left:0;
    background:url('http://www.element17.com/images/nav-left.png') center center no-repeat;
}

#sb-body:hover .sb-bignav {
    opacity:0.5;
    -webkit-opacity:0.5;
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
}

#sb-body .sb-bignav:hover {
    opacity:1.0;
    -webkit-opacity:1.0;
    -moz-opacity:1.0;
}

.sb-bignav {
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    z-index:400;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-opacity:0;
    -moz-opacity:0;
    transition: opacity .125s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .125s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity .125s ease-in;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DmAVQ/

​
The second problem is that you can not do the third item only with CSS.

"When either nav button is hovered directly, it is set at 100% opacity and the other nav button is set at 0% opacity."

You need to use JavaScript to do this.

Comment: [Specificity is not counted in "points" like that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809024/points-in-css-specificity)

Comment: Cool @BoltClock , did not know that. When I learned CSS still spoke in points. And to be honest, it always worked and always will work in 99.99% of cases. =)

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea...
Maybe you could do it by placing 2 clone navs in your `anchor` tags...
I made a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zNkcQ/5/

```
<div id="sb-body">
    <a id="sb-nav-previous" class="sb-bignav" title="Previous" onclick="Shadowbox.previous()">               
        <span class="sb-img-next"></span>              
        <span class="sb-img-previous"></span>
    </a> 
    <a id="sb-nav-next" class="sb-bignav" title="Next" onclick="Shadowbox.next()">              
        <span class="sb-img-previous"></span>              
        <span class="sb-img-next"></span>
    </a>
    <div id="sb-body-inner">
        <img style="position: absolute;" src="Corrosion.jpg" id="sb-player" height="405" width="609">
    </div>
</div>
.sb-img-previous{
    left:0;
    pointer-events: none;
    background:url('http://www.element17.com/images/nav-left.png') center center no-repeat;
}
.sb-img-next{
    right:0;
    pointer-events: none; 
    background:url('http://www.element17.com/images/nav-right.png') center center no-repeat;
}
.sb-img-previous, .sb-img-next{
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    etc...
}
#sb-nav-previous .sb-img-next,
#sb-nav-next .sb-img-previous,
#sb-nav-previous:hover .sb-img-previous,
#sb-nav-next:hover .sb-img-next{
    opacity: 0.5;
    pointer-events: none; //So each button will not be burdened by its duplicate...
}
#sb-nav-previous .sb-img-previous,
#sb-nav-next .sb-img-next,
#sb-nav-previous:hover .sb-img-next,
#sb-nav-next:hover .sb-img-previous{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: If you disable the pointer events then how can the buttons be clicked? Besides, wouldn't that instantly remove the hover state?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that it was targeting the clone navs.

Comment: The pointer-events are disabled for the clone buttons (the "previous" button contained in the next button's anchor?