Primefaces Dialog overwrite width per CSS
I am a frontend developer new in a team working with primefaces 13 in a Java project. I am building a simple dialog with
<p:dialog widgetVar="test" modal="true" resizable="false" draggable="false" header="Header" styleClass="my-dialog">

I want to set the width to a fix value per breakpoint, i.e.:
body .ui-dialog // same result with body .ui-dialog.my-dialog {
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
        width: 300px;
    }
    @media (min-width: 601px) {
        width: 400px;
    }
    @media (min-width: 1000px) {
        width: 500px;
    }
}

but this seems not be able to overwrite the primefaces own style since they are written as inline style on the element. I tried to use the custom CSS-Class in the selector, but same result. The only workaround I found is to set
.ui-dialog {
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
        min-width: 300px;
        max-width: 300px;
    }
}

Is there a better way to do this? I know of the "responsive" option, but I need to set a fix value in this case.
Edit: I don't understand why my question was closed, this is clearly not a duplicate of How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?

my CSS is loaded AFTER the primefaces CSS as I pointed out in my comment
my problem here is that primefaces write their rules as element.style, you can see here despite my CSS selector is much more precise (even with my custom class defined in StyleClass, which I although pointed out in my original question), I can't overwrite the inline CSS coming from primefaces.



Use a more specific CSS rule.

care to specify? Since it should be a general rule for all dialog in my project. I can't use too specified selector. But I already tried like .body .my-page-selector .page .ui-dialog {} and it didnt help

Please learn about CSS selectors. For all dialogs use body .ui-dialog. For your dialog only, you could use .ui-dialog.my-dialog.

like I mentioned in my previous comment and in my original post, I tried them both, neither of them could overwrite the css rules from primefaces

your css should be loaded after primefaces

first, it does. second, like I said, primefaces write their own styles as inline style on the element. So I don't think it matters which CSS is loaded first...

Ah, it's an element style you are trying to override. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910608/override-element-style-using-css

I was trying to avoid use !important in my CSS rules...  I am new to primefaces. Is it normal that primefaces write their CSS as inline style on the element? I used other component libraries before (i.e. bootstrap), can't remember they do this though...
