# closest() function is not working, why?

Tags: jquery

**HTML:**

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="button-wrap">
        <div class="content-wrap" id="button-1">one contents</div>
        <div class="controller">
            <div><a mce_href="#buttton-1" href="#buttton-1">button one </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#button-1').closest('.slider').css({'left':'-1200px'});
```

this is not working.

I have this script so far

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
        $('#button-1').closest('.slider').css({'background':'#f00 !important'});
        $('#button-2').closest('.slider').css({'left':'-1200px !important'});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide fiddle?

Comment: It works as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/beRj6/

Comment: Have you included the jQuery file?? Have you put your code inside the `$(document).ready(function() {`??

Comment: change the css to something obvious to see if the code itself works, maybe background-color or sth. like this. Because the code should work, another suggest would be the markup above is beeing used by for example a jquery-slider-script, it may be that it reorders the DOM and causes your not working function, another point is that to move it to the left it must be positioned relative or absolute, best case with an initial set "left:xyz" property

Comment: Your 2 blocks of jquery contradict: the first shows `left` being altered on `#button-1`; but the 2nd block shows only background-color being changed on `#button-1`, while `#button-2` gets its left changed. Is that your mix-up?

Comment: no, I changed to background-color so that is it working or not so the result is not working

Answer (score 0):

The `.slider` element needs to have position `absolute` or `relative` to be positioned using the `left` property.

Add the following css:

```
.slider{
    position: relative; //or absolute
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/U96gB/

Comment: Somebody explain the down-vote (that I just countered). This is most likely the correct explanation.

Comment: in my localhost I have add this css .slider{position: relative;} although not working. please see my edited question for script what I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I have copy/paste your code and it works :s
Make sure you have included jQuery library and maybe you forgot `position: relative;` on your `.slider`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#button-1').closest('.slider').css({'margin-left':'-1200px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `!important`, and it works in your fiddle -- jQuery's `.css()` gets tripped up on that part.

Some background on the problem can be found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2655976/613004

`!important` is not needed to override other styles from stylesheets, because jQuery applies all declarations that use `.css()` as  inline-styles, which will have higher specificity than any declaration from a stylesheet (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11934505/613004 for more on specificity calculations.)