# a:hover in css stylesheet doesn't show when

Tags: css, drupal, hover

when I do this, it works:

```
.view-current-sales .col-first a {color:#66ff66;}
```

when I add the hover, it doesn't work anymore

```
.view-current-sales .col-first a:hover {color:#66ff66;}
```

any ideas?

Comment: you have the same color. How you can see the changes?

Comment: What are you expecting to change when you hover? As @Coelho stated, there is no difference between your CSS...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing a few things with the a tag and its accompanied hover counterpart. Let's break it down really fast using a different example.

The HTML:

```
<div class="nohover3">
    <a href="#"> Test 3 </a>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.nohover3 a {
    color:#66ff66;
}
.nohover3 a:hover {
    color:blue;
}
```

Now, I am assuming you are enclosing these a tags in some sort of div or other containing tag to have it's own separate class. Now, this HTML renders one single a tag that is accompanied by two CSS elements. The first CSS element gives the a tag its starting color, meaning it automatically starts with that lime-green color you have provided me in the original question. The second element gives the hover a different color, in this case, the color goes from that lime-green to blue.

With that being said, let's look at your example but with a bit more cleaned up code:

The HTML

```
<div class="nohover2">
    <a href="#"> Test 2 </a>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.nohover2 a {
    color:#66ff66;
}
.nohover2 a:hover {
    color:#66ff66;
}
```

In this case, both the first and second element are producing the same color for the a tags. That means the color the a tag is to begin with (lime-green) is the same as the color when you hover over the a tag(also lime-green). Which means it stays the same color whether it is hovered or not.

To paint a clearer picture here is a JsFiddle to represent what I have just said:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/V5YD5/1/)

I apologize ahead of time for the poor class names, creating examples is not my strong suit at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

CSS uses a point-scoring system in determining which conflicting styles to use. Elements are worth 1 point, classes are worth 10 points and IDs are worth 100 points.

Try using "Inspect Element" in your chrome browser or similar in other browser types, it will tell you if another style is scoring higher and thus its hover style is used instead.

If thats the case try replacing the class reference for a:hover to an id reference to obtain a higher score for the a:hover you wish to use.

A nice description can be found here [Points in CSS specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809024/points-in-css-specificity)

If all else fails try tagging your hover style with "!important" to ensure the stype is used.