# Override descendant selector by class

Tags: html, css

Somehow the descendant selector overrides my `.red_p class`. How do I avoid that? I don't want to set a class for each `p` element.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .red_p {
        color: red;
      }

      #main p {
        color: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div id="main">
      <p>This should be blue.</p>           
      <p class="red_p">This should be red, but is blue.</p>             
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `!important` ? :) Yes, CSS is sometimes a pain in the ***

Comment: Because an `id`-selector is more specific than a class-selector, and a longer selector is presumed to be more specific/accurate. Remove `#main` from your second selector, and it should work fine. You may also want to read: [CSS selectors - Points in CSS Specificity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809024/points-in-css-specificity) (here on SO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS, there are rules for specificity ([quoted from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), and examples added to be clearer):

> The following list of selectors is by increasing specificity:
>
> - Universal selectors - ex: `*`
> - Type selectors - ex: `p`
> - Class selectors - ex: `.p_red`
> - Attributes selectors - ex: `[class="red"]`
> - Pseudo-classes - ex: `:hover`
> - ID selectors - ex: `#main`
> - Inline style - ex: `style` attribute in your HTML

So, you can add specificity to your selector. There are, in your case, several ways to do this :

```
#main .red_p
#main p.red_p
```

Or, third way, remove the `#main` in `#main p`, so it'll be less specific than your red p rule.

Answer (score 2):

Increase the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of blue. For the current code, `#main p` is much more specific than `.red_p` because it contains an id.

You can include an id in the red rule like `.red_p, #main .red_p` and move it after the blue rule (latter styles override earlier ones) or use `!important`.

Specificity works like this:

- If A is `!important` and B isn't, A is more specific than B. Halt.
- If A has more id selectors, A is more specific than B. Halt.
- If A is an inline style and B isn't, A is more specific than B. Halt.
- If A has more class selectors plus pseudo-class selectors plus attribute selectors than B, A is more specific than B. Halt.
- If A has more elements than B, A is more specific than B. Halt.
- If A is declared after B, A is more specific than B. Halt.

(The universal selector does not affect specificity)

http://cssspecificity.com has great examples and pictures.

Comment: +1 Good explanation and cool link - bookmarked this for further reference =)