# why doesn't this ">" direct descendent css selector work

Tags: html, css

Im wondering why this ">" selector doesn't work in this case below

```
    nav > ul > li > ul > li > a{
        color: red;
    }
```

but it does work in this case

```
    nav > ul > li > ul > li > a.item{
        color: red;
    }
```

The .a is the direct descendant of the li why do i have to specify the class name. shouldn't it get the child of the li? which is the .a

I just realized that it works if I just give you the above information but if I put in the rest of the css that I have before the above code, just putting the .a doesn't work. why is that happening

rest of css:

```
    html{
        height: 100%;
    }
    body{
        background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(315deg, #ddd, #ddd 40px, #aaa 40px, #aaa 80px);
        padding: 20px;
        height: 100%;
    }
    nav{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 960px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 0.6em;
        background-color: rgb(86,86,86);
        background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(75,75,75), rgb(86,86,86));
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow : 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 -1.5em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset, 0 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
    }
    nav > ul{
        padding: 0 10px;
    }

    nav > ul > li{
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        line-height: 3em;
        width: 100px;
        z-index: 2;
        position: relative;
        border-left: 1px solid #313131;
        box-shadow: 1px 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, -1px 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset;
    }
    nav > ul > li:nth-last-child(2){
        border-right: 1px solid #313131;
    }

    nav > ul > li > ul{
        position: absolute;
        left: -1px;
        top: 3em;
        clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    nav .item{
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 0.2em;
        padding-left: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    nav > ul > li > .item:hover + ul,
    nav > ul > li > ul:hover {
        clip: auto;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    nav > ul > li > ul{
        padding: 0.7em 0px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        border-top: none;
        background-color: rgb(117,189,70);
        background-color: rgba(119,172,48, 0.8);
        background-image: linear-gradient(left, rgba(117, 189, 70, 1), rgba(117,189,70,0.0));
    }
```

html

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li data-section="about-me">
            <a href="#" class="item">About me</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="item">Early years</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="item">First works</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="item">Today and tomorrow</a></li>
                <li class="cursor"><a href="#" class="item">back</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This issue is somewhere related to `CSS Specificity`. you may learn more about on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Points in CSS specificity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809024/points-in-css-specificity)

Comment: You probably don't need all those `>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that css selectors that specify a class name takes precedence over the descendant selectors. When you specify this selector...

```
 nav > ul > li > ul > li > a
```

it gets overridden by this one...

```
nav .item
```

and that's why the menu item shows its text in white, because class selectors take precedence over descendant selectors. However, when you specify this selector below the `nav .item` declaration...

```
nav > ul > li > ul > li > a.item
```

you are adding the class selector to the descendant which effectively overrides the previously specified `nav .item` selector

Comment: I disagree with the priority you are listing.... attribute is not in higher specificity than class...

Comment: @C-linkNepal Based on the MDN docs, I think you are wrong...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: @C-linkNepal and another one http://www.alternategateways.com/tutorials/css/css-101/part-four-the-css-order-of-precedence

Comment: I'm still with my concept that MDN still doesn't providing correct information because type selector isn't higher than class selector. Check this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/c1z2t0sa/

Comment: @C-linkNepal I think `Attribute Class selector` have `higher specificity` than simple `class selector` have a look at this example. http://jsbin.com/tidokezedinu/1/edit correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: @C-linkNepal you're probably right...I found those docs a bit misleading sometimes and specificity can get quite complex for a single answer...I guess I'm better off removing that specificity list

Comment: @KheemaPandey that's not exactly what's happening in your example. Swap the order of the declarations and you'll see what happens