# Why the warning "Selector specificity 0, 2, 0"?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

My Visual Studio keeps displaying the following warning (I think it's actually the Web Essentials plugin that produces it) but I'm not really clear why this is a problem? Can some explain please?

[image]

PS, **Yes I understand what specificity is and how to calculate it**, I just don't know why a specificity of `0,2,0` is a problem?

Comment: The above isn't the error message, it's standard hovering info when you move your mouse over a selector with WE. However, the problem you're facing is probably the same selector being specified twice in the same file.

Comment: Ah, that's stupid. I didn't notice that. I would of expected the popup to relate to the underscoring, thanks @Nit

Comment: Also, your correct, there was another rule with the same selector in the file so that was producing the underscoring..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above isn't the error message, it's standard hovering info when you move your mouse over a selector with WE. However, the problem you're facing is probably the same selector being specified twice in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

[Pekka's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809024/points-in-css-specificity/2809082#2809082) answer is practically correct, and probably the best way to think about the issue.

The starting point is 4 figures:

```
style  id   class element
0,     0,   0,    0
```

So in your case you have used 2 class names so its showing as 2 in the middle.