# How to override group of css class?

Tags: html, css

I am working with asp.net with c#.I have one stlyeSheet which use in all web forms.
but for only some particular div I want to change white-space value "*nowrap*" to "*initial*"

css Class

```
   .hint:after, [data-hint]:after {
        content: attr(data-hint);
        background: #383838;
        color: white;
        padding: 8px 10px;
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 12px;
        /*white-space: initial;*/
        white-space: nowrap;        
        max-width: 300px;           
    }
```

HTML control which i want to change this css class

```
 <div id="noteDiv" class="home_watchlist_colmn  col_Note hint--bottom" data-hint="<%#Eval("Note")%>">
   <div class="note_detail">
      <%#Eval("Note")%>
   </div>
 </div>
```

data-hint is for tool tip.This div inherit the given class. I want to change white-space for this "noteDiv".

Please provide proper solution with code.

Comment: why not just add `<div class="note_detail" style="white-space: nowrap">`? Or create a new class that inherits from the existing one?

Comment: Sorry, I only provide improper solution with code.

Comment: Because of i want to change this css for tool tip (data-hint) and its in "noteDiv"

Comment: reading up on css specificity should help http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2809024/1385672

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match against the id using `#`

```
#noteDiv {
    white-space: initial
}
```

or

```
#noteDiv:after {
    white-space: initial
}
```

If you need to overwrite the first block of CSS you mentioned.

Comment: this is not working!! still apply style from ".hint:after, [data-hint]:after"

Comment: Thanks for giving solution. `#noteDiv:after {
    white-space: initial
}` work for me. Can you please explain in detail how this work?

Comment: There's not much to it. in CSS `#` matches an id, and your original css already had an `:after` selector, so it needed to match