# How does Flask resolve ambiguous routes?

Tags: flask

Suppose I have a function decorated with `@app.route('/api/<path:path>')` and another function decorated with `@app.route('/<path:path>')`. The url path `/api/foo` matches against both routes. Does Flask offer a guarantee for which function will be called?

Comment: Can you explain how come `@app.route('/<path:path>')` will resolve `/api/foo` ?

Comment: @RajaSimon It resolves with `path = '/api/foo`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer to this in the `Flask` [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/design/):

> `Flask` uses the `Werkzeug` routing system which was designed to
>   automatically order routes by complexity. This means that you can
>   declare routes in arbitrary order and they will still work as
>   expected. This is a requirement if you want to properly implement
>   decorator based routing since decorators could be fired in undefined
>   order when the application is split into multiple modules.
>
> Another design decision with the `Werkzeug` routing system is that
>   routes in `Werkzeug` try to ensure that `URLs` are unique. `Werkzeug` will
>   go quite far with that in that it will automatically redirect to a
>   canonical `URL` if a route is ambiguous.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @RajaSimon Please read answer : `which was designed to automatically order routes by complexity`

Comment: And staff like this you could always test by writing `print("NUMBER 1")` and in the other `print("NUMBER 2")`...

Comment: @kemis any idea how `complexity` is compared? Is it at all like [CSS specificity points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2809024/673991)? I was hoping for clues [here](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/routing/) but haven't found anything yet.