# CSS Specificity calculation

Tags: html, css

I've recently started working with CSS and came across this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance) where a table defining the specificity values have been mentioned. While implementing this, 11 element selectors must have a specificity of 11 and one class must have a specificity of 10, the priority of class was more than the element selectors even though it had a greater total specificity. I'm a little confused as to how this is calculated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Points in CSS specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809024/points-in-css-specificity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a doubt which i had faced when i had started working with CSS. But this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809024/points-in-css-specificity/) will help you.

Good luck learning CSS!