# CSS make hover override active class

Tags: css

I want to make my hover color override my active class color.

Here is my hover:

```
.tabs nav a:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #1E528A;
}
```

here is my active li class:

```
.tabs nav li.active a {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #3792F5;
}
```

When I hover over my active class color takes precedence. I want the hover to take precedence over my active class color when hovered over. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try maybe switch their places in the .css file or `<style>` tags?

Sometimes the order in which you code your CSS makes a difference

Comment: Use specificity: add `.tabs nav li:active a:hover` and set it to the same as your other hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
.tabs nav a:hover,
.tabs nav li.active a:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #1E528A;
}
```

or use important:

```
.tabs nav a:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #1E528A !important;
}
```

Hope it helps.

---

Comment: Thanks! that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a specificity problem. Typically this is solved by using class names on the target element itself instead of "let's traverse all the way down the DOM" selectors like `.tabs nav li.active a`. Therefore, to fix this problem you could add a class name, like `.navigation-link` to each of the `<a>` elements. One popularly recommended CSS methodology that avoids this problem is [BEM](http://getbem.com/). Take a look at this question: [Points in CSS specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2809024/2773837)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
.tabs nav li.active a:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #3792F5;
}
```

It should work, but it's **too generic** and you need to specify all the nested selectors. 
As suggested in a comment, you can use a descriptive class name, somethink like:

```
a.menuLink:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #3792F5;
}
```

In this way you only need to target your `a` element with the right class.

Finally, avoid using `!important`, it's a bad practice. You should use !important only when you don't have any other options, and this is not the case.