# Why does SASS modify chained selectors of the same name when using extend?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Given the following HTML / SASS code:

```
<div class="a">hello</div>

%color {
    color: blue;
}
.a {
  color: red;
}
.a.a {
  @extend %color;
}
```

I was expecting the resulting color to be blue (due to the more specific `.a.a` selector<sup>1</sup>) with output something like this:

```
.a.a {
   color: blue;
}
.a {
   color: red;
}
```

But actually, the resulting color is red, with SASS output:

```
.a {
  color: blue;
}

.a {
  color: red;
}
```

I find this quite counter-intuitive!

Why does SASS refactor my `.a.a` selector to `.a`?

Just in case you don't believe me, here's [a codepen demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/jeeJQx) (click view compiled css to see the CSS output)

**NOTE:**

This 'refactoring' of the selector only occurs to the declarations *within the extend.*

So in the following SASS:

```
%color {
    color: blue;
}
.a.a {
  @extend %color;
  position: relative;
}
```

The output is:

```
.a {
  color: blue;
}

.a.a {
  position: relative;
}
```

([Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/ZqVLEK))

---

<sup>1</sup>See [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#example-ef24c365):

> Note: Repeated occurrences of the same simple selector are allowed and
>   do increase specificity.

Comment: I think that SASS is reasoning that an element with a class name of "a" as well as a class name of "a" is the same as an element with a class name of "a".

Comment: On the other hand, this happens only in the presence of `@extend`. Hm.

Comment: I guess this would be example of SASS preprocessor's optimizing your code.

Comment: In css `.a` and `.a.a` are identical, so SASS intelligently saves some bytes.

Comment: @connexo no, they aren't identical, one is more specific than the other

Comment: @connexo But they are not! `.a.a` has a higher specificity! Change the OP's SCSS to `.a {
  color: red;
 &.a {
  color: blue;
}
}` and see the color change!

Comment: It makes absolutely zero sense that `.a.a` would by any means make the rule more specific than `.a`. If that is true (haven't checked), it's clearly an error/misdesign in the specification. Besides `.a.a` being really bad code, but that's another issue.

Comment: btw at [SASS Meister](https://www.sassmeister.com/) it is compiled correctly even with `@extend`. Try updating SASS.

Comment: related : https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1596 ... old but also related: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/324

Comment: @connexo *It makes absolutely zero sense* : this is how specifity always worked (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809024/points-in-css-specificity) and this is something we can use in order to override some external style like doing `.a:not(#random_ID)` [we increase the speficity using an ID without changing the rule]

Comment: Trying to win a specificity war by concatenating the same class selector multiple times seems like a really dumb approach.

Comment: @connexo the issue is not there. A bad approach or not, the compiler shouldn't change the specifity that the user defined. Optimization shouldn't affect the behavior.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Agreed, especially all the SASS compiles should reliably create identical results with regard to how the result works.

Comment: @connexo While I understand your frustration, it's no use saying "but this feature makes no sense" as if other features in CSS do make sense!

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, the result depends on the parsing engine. If you use `DartSass v1.6.2` (default on sassmeister.com), it outputs your expected result:

```
.a.a {
  color: blue;
}

.a {
  color: red;
}
```

Check on [sassmeister.com](https://www.sassmeister.com) (you can also switch parsing engines there).

`LibSass v3.5.2` creates the result you complained about:

```
.a {
  color: blue;
}

.a {
  color: red;
}
```