# Bootsfaces - Accordion: Change arrows to glyphicons and add Subtitle

Tags: css, jsf, bootsfaces

A normal Bootstrap Accordion would look like this:

Code:

```
<b:accordion>
  <b:panel id="panel1" title="Item 1">Content 1</b:panel>
  <b:panel id="panel2" title="Item 2">Content 2</b:panel>
  <b:panel id="panel3" title="Item 3">Content 3</b:panel>
</b:accordion>
```

Picture

[image: Accordion]

How could I change the arrows here to glyphicons?

Also, I am trying to change have a subtitle added to the title like this:
[image: Title with subtitle in accordion]

Which works fine in html as i can just add it to the `<div class="panel-heading">` but i have no Idea how I could manage this with bootsfaces...

Comment: I don't really understand your question as the arrow icon already is a glyph icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Icon

See my comment for the first part of your question. The icon already is a Glyph icon:

```
.panel-heading a.panel-title-link:after {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\e114";
    float: right;
    color: grey;
}
```

If you want to change the icon, you need to override the CSS rule with a more specific one. For example:

```
body .panel-heading a.panel-title-link:after {
    content: "\e114"; // Change the icon here
}
```

Prefixing the rule with `body` will make it more specific.

See also:

- [Points in CSS specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809024/points-in-css-specificity)
- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles) (although it's targeting PrimeFaces, the same principals apply here).

### Header

The header is demonstrated in the showcase: https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/layout/Accordion.jsf

However, the JSF markup they show is [incorrect](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFacesWeb/pull/65/files). It actually is:

```
<b:panel id="panel3">Content 3
  <f:facet name="heading">
    <h:outputText value="Panel heading with a facet in place of a title " />
    <b:badge style="margin-left:10px" value="since version 0.4" />
  </f:facet>
  <f:facet name="footer">
    Footer of panel 3
  </f:facet>
<b:panel>
```

See: https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFacesWeb/blob/master/src/main/webapp/layout/Accordion.xhtml

You could use headings there, but you run into the issue it will be wrapped into an anchor attribute, which will result in invalid HTML. Also the position of the icon will be wrong. If you want a proper solution, try [submitting a feature request](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues), or, if you can, create it and submit a pull request.

Comment: Thank you, i just want to change the glyphicon it is now (the arrows) into other glyphicons

Comment: but how could i now actually add a subtitle to the heading?