# Is it possible to unwrap a HTML element using CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a content management system that generates code like

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

and depending on the query it might also generate

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="item">Item 1</div>
        <div class="item">Item 2</div>
        <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want ***container*** be a flexbox container, and ***item*** be flexbox children in all cases.

Is there a way to unwrap the ***section*** element (=make the browser ignore this div layer - so that the ***item*** elements will be treated as if they where direct children of ***container***)?

Or is that impossible with pure CSS?

Comment: Not generically, yet. There's a possible saviour coming: `display: contents`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as children elements are concerned, `.section` is a child element of `.container` and `.item` elements are children of `.section`. There isn't a way to ignore this via CSS.

I'd recommend you copy the styles of `.container` to `.section` and just make the necessary adjustments there.

It would help if you shared your current styles.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that like this:

```
.container, .container > .section {
    display: flex;
    ...
}
.container > .item, .container > .section > .item {
    ...
}
```

It wouldn’t be a good idea to remove the section element because that is there for a reason. But the css above will take care of both cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can add new rules for case when CMS creates additional tag and then add specificity them to increase chances that correct rule will be applied:

```
div.container div.section {
   display: flex;
}
```

[Read more about specificity here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809024/how-are-the-points-in-css-specificity-calculated)