# Why the same CSS class twice in a row

Tags: css

I saw the following line in a code:

```css
.className.className {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Is there a reason to write this twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely used to increase the [specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809024/how-are-the-points-in-css-specificity-calculated) of the selector.

It would probably be better if it was rewritten to change the source order instead.

Comment: A colleague told me that this is a softer solution to `@important`. So I think you are absolutely right and that the css should rather be restructured.

Answer (score 1):

Typo maybe. below is valid though.

All `<li>` elements with a class list that includes both "spacious" and "elegant"

For example, class="elegant retro spacious"

```
li.spacious.elegant {
  margin: 2em;
}
```

[read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo!
Technically this code will apply to an element with the following classes: `"className"` or `"className"`.
But because one match is enough and they are the same name it doesn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

Nope.
Maybe just typo. It has no meaning on css.