# Override @import CSS from external widget

Tags: css

I want to override the css of an external widget on my website.
It has a wrapper div with a margin, which I want to change.

When I change it in the Chrome DevTools it works perfectly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YpO5.png)

But when i add this to my CSS, it won't change anything:

```
.trusted-stars-service-widget .wrapper {
margin: 0em;
}
```

Help please.

I tried

```
.trusted-stars-service-widget .wrapper {
margin: 0em;
}
```

and also !important

but it didn't work.

Comment: Change the order of the widget CSS file and your custom CSS file. If there are 2 same rules, the last wins.

Comment: Or, increase the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of your CSS rule.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are the points in CSS specificity calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809024/how-are-the-points-in-css-specificity-calculated)